# After installing a program using opam, how do I run it?

Tags: ocaml, opam

I successfully installed a program using opam: `opam install lustre-v6`. *But how to run it?* I stupidly tried `lv6`, `opam lv6`, `ocaml lv6`, `opam lustre-v6`, `opam run lustre-v6`, `ocaml lustre-v6`, etc., to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to @Ayrat 's answer: the important command here is

```
eval `opam env`
```

which detects your shell and sets appropriate environment variables. This is because opam installs binaries to a custom directory within your current opam switch, and that directory is not in your system's search path. You probably want to put the command above into your shell's init script.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentations:

> lv6 edge.lus

http://www-verimag.imag.fr/DIST-TOOLS/SYNCHRONE/reactive-toolbox/#org234ffeb